# ROSARIA Tutorial Groovy catkin_make issue

Tags: ros, catkin-make, catkin, aria, rosaria

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I've been running through this tutorial for a few days, i'm now seeing a few mistakes I made [not installing the Aria-2.7.2 file and Mobilesim-0.5.0 (as I'm not attached to a robot at the moment)] but I've done all that now(the ROSARIA tutorial should probably point out that you should do that ahead of time but I suppose I just skipped that step). Now when I've made my workspace and I use the catkin_make command in the ~/catkin_ws directory everything runs fine until I get to

```
    [ 83%] Built target ROSARIA_gencfg
Linking CXX executable /home/****/catkin_ws/devel/lib/ROSARIA/RosAria
/usr/bin/ld: skipping incompatible /usr/local/Aria/lib/libAria.so when searching for -lAria
/usr/bin/ld: cannot find -lAria
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
make[2]: *** [/home/****/catkin_ws/devel/lib/ROSARIA/RosAria] Error 1
make[1]: *** [amor-ros-pkg/ROSARIA/CMakeFiles/RosAria.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [all] Error 2
Invoking "make" failed
```

and now I don't know what I can do to fix it.
Can anyone help?

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/59579/rosaria-tutorial-groovy-catkin_make-issue/) by [Guru666](https://answers.ros.org/users/4545/guru666/) on ROS Answers with karma: 21 on 2013-03-29

Post score: 0

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

Maybe you've installed wrong version of ARIA (32 bit version on 64 bit machine or vice versa). Please, update python-rosdep package (or rosdep through pip) to version 0.10.15. Then run

```
rosdep update
rosdep install ROSARIA
```

This should install ARIA automatically. After that catkin_make should work.

---

Originally posted by [JKS](https://answers.ros.org/users/357/jks/) with karma: 306 on 2013-03-29

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 3

---

#### Original comments

**Comment by [Guru666](https://answers.ros.org/users/4545/guru666/) on 2013-03-29**:
I've tried rosdep install ROSARIA
ERROR: Rosdep cannot find all required resources to answer your query
Missing resource ROSARIA
ROS path [0]=/opt/ros/groovy/share/ros
ROS path [1]=/opt/ros/groovy/share
ROS path [2]=/opt/ros/groovy/stacks
this is what it spits back obviously these paths exist.

**Comment by [Guru666](https://answers.ros.org/users/4545/guru666/) on 2013-03-29**:
also this initial error would be in the tutorial 1.5, the first step. I will have to make sure I have the correct Aria version installed

**Comment by [Guru666](https://answers.ros.org/users/4545/guru666/) on 2013-03-29**:
Alright I made sure the Aria was up to date and the correct version for my computer and everything seems to work now. Thanks!